# How to translate database schema with shared primary key to hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have the following postgres schema with a `primary key` defined as both `PK` and `foreign key`:

```
CREATE TABLE main_table(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT main_table_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    //some fields
)

CREATE TABLE test(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_pk PRIMARAY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT test_fk FOREIGN KEY (id)
        REFERENCES main_table (id) MATCH SIMPLE
)
```

I want to create a hibernate mapping that would autogenerates the same schema:

```
@Entity
public class MainTable {
    @Id private int id;

    @OneToOne
    private Test test;
}

@Entity
public class Test {
    @Id private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_id"))
    private MainTable mainTable;
}
```

Result: the foreign key constraint is missing completely:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_pk PRIMARAY KEY (id)
)
```

Why is the foreign key constraint missing? What can I do?

What's interesting: the following would create a foreign key entry in Test table, but as a separate column:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn
private MainTable mainTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

If two entites have one primary key may be there is inheritance between them? Actually it looks like join-table inheritance: [Inheritance mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html). According [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html) PrimaryKeyJoinColumn *is used to join the primary table of an entity subclass in the JOINED mapping strategy*. So you cannot use PrimaryKeyJoinColumn without inheritance. It is simple ignored.

You can try:

```
  @Entity
  public class MainTable {
      @Id
      private int id;

      @OneToOne(mappedBy = "mainTable" )
      private Test test;
      .......
  }

  @Entity
  public class Test {
     @Id
     private int id;

     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_id"))
     private MainTable mainTable;
     .....
 }
```

But there is bug in schema generator - it does not create foreign key. You can create it manually.

Comment: They are tables with rows identified by the same id = primary key. One table should be the "root", but I want to have two tables to separated contents.